# JAX-WS web service generation fails

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, apache-axis

I'm trying to generate a JAX-WS Web Service from a Java Bean using the tooling in IBM Rational Team Concert 5.0. WAS 8 as application server. I get this weird error message in the wizard.

Any clues?

```
Errors occurred during wsgen.
  Errors occurred during wsgen.
  error: compilation failed, errors should have been reported


warning: The apt tool and its associated API are planned to be
removed in the next major JDK release.  These features have been
superseded by javac and the standardized annotation processing API,
javax.annotation.processing and javax.lang.model.  Users are
recommended to migrate to the annotation processing features of
javac; see the javac man page for more information.
Note:   ap round: 1
Problem encountered during annotation processing; 
see stacktrace below for more information.
com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.ModelerException: [failed to localize] Could not get TypeDeclaration for: se.mynamespace.exposure.exception.ServiceGeneralException in apt round: 1()
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAP.onError(WebServiceAP.java:229)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceWrapperGenerator.generateExceptionBeans(WebServiceWrapperGenerator.java:188)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceWrapperGenerator.processMethod(WebServiceWrapperGenerator.java:173)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.visitMethodDeclaration(WebServiceVisitor.java:449)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.mirror.declaration.MethodDeclarationImpl.accept(MethodDeclarationImpl.java:71)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.processMethods(WebServiceVisitor.java:374)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.postProcessWebService(WebServiceVisitor.java:340)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceWrapperGenerator.postProcessWebService(WebServiceWrapperGenerator.java:141)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.visitInterfaceDeclaration(WebServiceVisitor.java:120)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.mirror.declaration.InterfaceDeclarationImpl.accept(InterfaceDeclarationImpl.java:62)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.inspectEndpointInterface(WebServiceVisitor.java:420)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceVisitor.visitClassDeclaration(WebServiceVisitor.java:141)
    at com.sun.tools.apt.mirror.declaration.ClassDeclarationImpl.accept(ClassDeclarationImpl.java:125)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.tools.ws.processor.modeler.annotation.WebServiceAP.buildModel(WebServiceAP.java:329)
```